# Make my rfxtrx433e working with a UWP app on Raspbery Pie 2 with Windows IOT

Tags: win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, iot, usbserial, windowsiot

I'm developing a domotic UWP app and I'm trying to make my app working on my Raspberry under Windows IOT.

When I run the app on my computer everything works fine. I'm able to get the corresponding COM port and to communicate with my device.

When launch my app on the Raspberry, then I'm not able to get the corresponding Serial interface. I tried with all COM port but without any success. I then thought that it was a driver issue but it seems that everything is fine with the drivers => When I plug my rfxtrx433 I can see that my IOT system recognize it (it displays rfxtrx433 under connected devices section and devcon command says that drivers are running for this device)

Has someone any idea what I have to do to communicate with my device?

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as the driver for Win10 on IoT does not exist. Have you looked at the hardware compatibility list?

https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm